# Creating a basic service for CRUD operations

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, blazor, abp

I wrote the following code to summarize all CRUD operations in my DomainServices, but it throws an error on first use.

```
// generic class

public class GenericManager<T>  : DomainService where T : class, IEntity<int>
{
    public readonly IRepository<T, int> _genericRepository;

    public async Task<T> GetAsync(int id) => await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(_genericRepository.Where(m => m.Id == id));
    public async Task AddAsync(T entity) => await _genericRepository.InsertAsync(entity);
    public async Task AddManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities) => await _genericRepository.InsertManyAsync(entities);
    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity) => await _genericRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
    public async Task UpdateManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities) => await _genericRepository.UpdateManyAsync(entities);
    public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity) => await _genericRepository.DeleteAsync(entity);
}

// my domain services
public class ClientManager : GenericManager<Client>
{
    public async Task<Client> GetClientByNameAsync(string userName) => await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(_genericRepository.Where(m => m.UserName == userName));
    public async Task<Client> FindClientWithVKID(string vkid) => await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(_genericRepository.Where(m => m.VkId == vkid));
}

// usage my domain service other code
var user = await _clientManager.GetAsync(userId);
```

But as a result of the program's work, such an error is issued

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at RenewalTML.Data.ClientManager.GetClientByNameAsync(String userName) in 
C:\Users\Fearp\source\repos\RenewalTML\RenewalTML\Data\User\ClientManager.cs:line 15
at RenewalTML.Data.ClientAuthServices.LoginIsReady(UserLoginModel model) in 
C:\Users\Fearp\source\repos\RenewalTML\RenewalTML\Data\User\ClientAuthServices.cs:line 236
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation 
invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
at 
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
at Volo.Abp.GlobalFeatures.GlobalFeatureInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation 
invocation)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult] 
(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation 
invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
at 
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
at Volo.Abp.Validation.ValidationInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult] 
(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation 
invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
at 
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.ProceedByLoggingAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation 
invocation, IAuditingHelper auditingHelper, IAuditLogScope auditLogScope)
at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.ProcessWithNewAuditingScopeAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation 
invocation, AbpAuditingOptions options, ICurrentUser currentUser, IAuditingManager 
auditingManager, IAuditingHelper auditingHelper)
at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.ProcessWithNewAuditingScopeAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation 
invocation, AbpAuditingOptions options, ICurrentUser currentUser, IAuditingManager 
auditingManager, IAuditingHelper auditingHelper)
at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult] 
(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation 
invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
at 
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult] 
(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
at RenewalTML.Pages.Client.Authorization.LoginExecuted(EditContext editContext) in 
C:\Users\Fearp\source\repos\RenewalTML\RenewalTML\Pages\Client\Authorization.razor:line 227
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

I originally expected an error. How can I create such a workable code so that I don't write the same code for CRUD operations in my application?

I user: .NET 5.0 Blazor Web Server, EFCore + mysql
Volo.Abp version: 4.3.3

Comment: Is userId an int?  I don't see where it is declared

Comment: So what is an `IRepository`, how is it created (and destroyed) ?  etc. All relevant code is missing.

Comment: @DJ Burb yes integer, it is read from the .blazor fields of the page

Comment: @Henk Holterman IRepository - is part of the abp.io framework APB.DOMAIN.REPOSITORY https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `public readonly IRepository<T, int> _genericRepository;` is `null` since you are never initialising it. Thus, when calling `_genericRepository.Where(m => m.UserName == userName)` in `ClientManager` you get a LINQ exception saying that the `source` (_genericRepository) is `null`.

You probably need to initialise the genericRepository with the injected instance by your DI container inside the constructor of `ClientManager`.

**Update**

Referring to the same documentation of the framework you are using, this is basically the missing part.

[image: Screenshot detailing how OP is not initializing the repository in the constructor]

Probably something like this is what you need:

```
public class ClientManager : GenericManager<Client>
{

    public ClientManager(IRepository<Client, Guid> clientRepository)
    {
        _genericRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    
...
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman hmm you are right...  but that line of code it's sketchy anyway. Why is the OP doing a `.Where` operation in the `_genericRepository`? Maybe s/he made `IRepository<T, int>` implement the enumerator interface 

Comment: it is initialized in my other service

`public class ClientAuthServices : ApplicationService, IClientAuthServices
    {
        private readonly ClientManager _clientManager;
        public ClientAuthServices(ClientManager clientManager)
        {
            _clientManager = clientManager;
        }

...`

Comment: the official abp.io documentation does not say anything about generic services, and perhaps iRepository cannot work with '<T> where T: class, IEntity <int>'

Comment: It works if you don't create a genericRepository, I thought it would work if you just inherit the functionality of the genericRepository to some other repository.

Comment: After looking at that library you linked I think my suspicion. The problem is that you are not initializing the IRepository that the `ClientManager` is trying to use. `_genericRepository` is null! Define a constructor for ClientManager, get the generic repository instance injected and assign it to `_genericRepository`. @JigglyDezar

Comment: One more clarification, I have never registered my services and repository anywhere, because the abp framework did it for me, apparently by inheriting DomainService and ApplicationService, but this does not work with genericRepository

Comment: [image](https://i.imgur.com/6lsADuN.png) 
Here's what I get after finishing off the constructor in the genericRepository
how do i create and inject iRepository into the GenericRepository constructor?

Comment: I know for sure that if we create an iRepository in the ClientManager constructor, then it will work, but how to pass it to the genericRepository

Comment: Yes it works, I will finally solve the problem with the same CRUD requests. Thanks.